# Which bit numbering is used by big-endian ARM: "MSB 0" or "LSB 0"?

Tags: arm, bit, endianness

Which bit numbering is used by big-endian ARM (ex. ARMv4, ARMv5, ARMv6): `MSB 0` or `LSB 0`?
Please, provide a source.

Comment: It is not architecture defined, it is system defined. The majority are configured as little-endian.  If a device is marketed as a network SOC, it is probably big-endian.  Some support changing endianess at boot time.

Comment: armv4/5 and armv6 big endian are not equal btw.   bit numbering doesnt change lsbit is bit 0

Comment: the different arms can be changed at runtime depending on the architecture as well as having instructions to handle byte swapping.  running any arm big endian is unwise.  think of it as a marketing checkbox...and note again that pre armv6 and during and after use different big endian schemes.   best to do your system engineering and not make assumptions about things based on a label.

Comment: runtime depends on the chip vendor and how they strap the core.  if they hard strap it one way or the other then you are stuck, if they provide a control register then you might have a chance, but it would default one way in the logic.  some you can change on the fly without the strap.